# Use a loop to subset a vector by date range

Tags: r

I have files which a date stamp in their name, I'm trying to only import a certain range of dates.

First I load all of the files available into R as a vector:

```
files <- c("FileName_2013_06_10_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_11_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_12_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_13_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_14_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_15_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_16_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_17_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_18_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_19_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_20_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_21_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_22_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_23_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_24_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_25_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_26_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_27_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_28_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_29_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_30_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_01_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_02_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_03_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_04_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_05_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_06_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_07_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_08_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_09_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_10_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_11_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_12_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_13_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_14_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_15_00_00_00.txt")
```

Each filename stands for `FileName_yyyy_mm_dd_HH_MM_SS.txt`

Of these, I only wish to import the following days (`Year`, `Month`, and `Day` are the only criteria I'm looking for):

```
datesub <- c("FileName_2013_06_25_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_26_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_27_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_28_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_06_29_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_06_30_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_01_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_02_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_03_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_04_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_05_00_00_00.txt", "FileName_2013_07_06_00_00_00.txt", 
"FileName_2013_07_07_00_00_00.txt")
```

Easy enough to do a subset (`files[files %in% datesub]`), however, complications arise because the files sometimes have this formatting:

- `FileName_2013_06_27_12_21_13.txt`,
- `FileName_2013_06_28_00_00_00comb.txt`,
- or any combination of the prior examples.

I tried subsetting the data before I imported it into R by using regular expressions, but as soon as I tried to do a range of more than two months things started to get messy.

How can I subset my data? I think it is possible to do using a `for` loop, but I'm not sure.

I'm open to all and any suggestions. If my question is not clear enough let me know and I will do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions to get just the Y_m_d piece from datesub, and then use regular expressions again to get the files that match the Y_m_d piece:

```
datesubclean <- sapply(
  regmatches(datesub, regexec("^FileName_([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2})", datesub)),
  `[`, 2L
)
files.sub <- sapply(datesubclean, grep, x=files, value=T)
unname(files.sub)
# [1] "FileName_2013_06_25_00_00_00.txt" "FileName_2013_06_26_00_00_00.txt"
# [3] "FileName_2013_06_27_00_00_00.txt" "FileName_2013_06_28_00_00_00.txt"
# [5] "FileName_2013_06_29_00_00_00.txt" "FileName_2013_06_30_00_00_00.txt"
# [7] "FileName_2013_07_01_00_00_00.txt" "FileName_2013_07_02_00_00_00.txt"
# [9] "FileName_2013_07_03_00_00_00.txt" "FileName_2013_07_04_00_00_00.txt"
# [11] "FileName_2013_07_05_00_00_00.txt" "FileName_2013_07_06_00_00_00.txt"
# [13] "FileName_2013_07_07_00_00_00.txt"
```

Then all you have to do is loop through the file names and open them.

`regexec` is a special regular expression function that allows us to retrieve the captured matches (stuff in parens inside regular expressions), and `regmatches` is able to read the special object that `regexec` produces.  The first `sapply` is just to get the 2nd element from the `regmatches` output, because `regmatches` also returns the full match as the first element in addition to the sub-pattern capture.

Comment: Thank you! I still quite don't understand what exactly you did, so I have a bit of reading to do tonight. Edit: I can generate `datesubclean` from the get-go using `seq.Date`, so now at least I understand what is going on :)

Comment: Just look at the result of executing `regmatches(datesub, regexec("^FileName_([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2})", datesub))`.  Trying to understand the output of `regexec` is more challenging (and mostly unnecessary).